# Performance Problems with Number-Recognizing AI Functions

Tags: machine-learning

I created an AI function that recognizes numbers using MNIST.

```
trainingData = RandomSample[ResourceData["MNIST", "TrainingData"], 20000];  
ai = Classify[trainingData]
```

And for the test, I made a sketchpad that can draw numbers.

```
sc = 64; 
imgdata = Table[1., {i, sc}, {j, sc}];
blank = Table[1., {i, sc}, {j, sc}];
p1 = {10, 26}; p2 = {10, 25}; 
PixelPos[] :=  Replace[MousePosition[
"Graphics"], {{i_, j_} :> Round[{sc - j, i}], _ :> None}];
Attributes[PaintDot] = {HoldFirst}; 
PaintDot[data_Symbol, p : {i1_, j1_}] := 
Block[{dim = Length[data]}, 
Do[If[EuclideanDistance[N[{i, j}], N[p]] < 2.5, 
 data[[i, j]] = 0.], {i, Max[i1 - 3, 1], Min[i1 + 3 dim]}, {j, 
 Max[j1 - 3, 1], Min[j1 + 3, dim]}]]; 
Attributes[PaintLine] = {HoldFirst}; 
PaintLine[data_Symbol, {i1_, j1_}, {i2_, j2_}] :=  
Block[{dim, indices, ib, ie, jb, je}, 
indices = InterpolatePoints[N[{i1, j1}], N[{i2, j2}], 1]; 
{ib, ie} = Sort[{i1, i2}]; 
      {jb, je} = Sort[{j1, j2}]; {{ib, jb}, {ie, je}} = 
Clip[{{ib, jb} - 3, {ie, je} + 3}, {1, Length[data]}]; 
Quiet[Do[
 If[Min[(EuclideanDistance[N[{i, j}], #1] & ) /@ indices] < 2.5, 
  data[[i, j]] = 0.], {i, ib, ie}, 
          {j, jb, je}]]; ];
InterpolatePoints[p1_, p2_, r_] := 
Module[{d, v}, d = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2]; 
If[d < 2*r, Return[{p1, p2}]]; v = Normalize[p2 - p1];    
Developer`ToPackedArray[
Append[p2][Table[p1 + i*v, {i, 0., d, r}]], Real]]; 
SmartCrop[img_] := 
Block[{crop = ImageCrop[img], w, h, h2}, {w, h} = 
ImageDimensions[crop]; h2 = Ceiling[h/2]; 
If[w < h2, ImageCrop[crop, {h2, h}, Padding -> White], crop]];
Column[ { EventHandler[Dynamic[If[MatrixQ[imgdata], gf = Framed[
   Image[imgdata, ImageSize -> {200, 200}], 
   FrameStyle -> Lighter@Gray], None], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {imgdata}],        
"MouseDown" :> (p1 = p2 = PixelPos[]; PaintDot[imgdata, p1]; ), "MouseDragged" :> (p1 = p2; p2 = PixelPos[]; 
 PaintLine[imgdata, p1, p2]; ), PassEventsDown -> Automatic,   PassEventsUp -> True, 
         Method -> "Preemptive"], Button[Style["Delete SketchPad", 12, Brown], imgdata = blank, ImageSize -> 207] }]
Dynamic@ImageResize[ImageCrop@gf[[1]], {28, 28}]
Dynamic@ai[ImageResize[ImageCrop@gf[[1]], {28, 28}], "TopProbabilities"]
```

More than 10,000 training data was sufficient, but the test results were below expectations.

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: I get better performance with a neural network than if you let mathematica select logistic regression or nearest neighbour by default. Look into the `Method` option of `Classify`. Also remove all of your cropping.

Comment: Thank you! I did an image crop. You mean NetTrain makes better performance than Classify? Even if that is true, the results of Classify are far below expectations. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: I've been looking at this and I can't say anything else is wrong with your code - The ImageCrop is potentially bad because MNIST integers usually have some white space around the edge; cropping will cause the digit to fill the whole box. But even if I use `Binarize`, and `ResamplingMethod->"Nearest"` to remove the 'ringing' artifacts you get when resizing the image, it still has some problems. Most notably, drawing a 4 with the vertical connected fails, and drawing a 3 in the bottom left corner always results in a 9. Maybe your training needs more rounds.